# origin does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, github, repository

I created a new repository online at github, where i have an account. The project is at, say:

https://github.com/myname/myproject

Now I want to add, commit and push things to that project from my file system.
So I opened the terminal on Ubuntu, went to the directory that I want to make into a git folder and typed git init

```
    ~/myfolder$ git init
```

then I typed

```
    ~/myfolder$ git clone git@github.com:myname/myproject.git
```

then I typed git status, to find that a whole lot of files are untracked. So I added one of them, like

```
    ~/myfolder/mysubfolder$ git add subfolderfile.txt
```

I even committed by

```
    ~/myfolder/mysubfolder$ git commit -m "Some comment"
```

but then pushing it

```
    ~/myfolder/mysubfolder$ git push origin master
```

gives

*fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.*

I read other questions on this forum but my level of coding sophistication is that of your average grandma, so I tried

```
    $ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:myname/myproject.git
```

but that didn't work: *No such remote 'origin'*. I am really at a loss. 
Please explain in greatgrandpa style what I need to do. Prior knowledge=0. E.g I'd prefer "the big black window" over the Terminal or else I'd be very happy to have a brief explanation of what it is. Thanks so much.

Comment: have a look here https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

Comment: Thanks rdRahul for your link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue here is almost certainly caused by you running `git init` first and then cloning your project into the same directory using the `git clone` command. And even if you can fix the issue by adding the remote to the empty repository that you initialized on your machine, you don't want to do that because you will then have two git repositories, one nested inside the other.

Because of the above, if you don't have any valuable changes in the project on your local machine, it would make things more simple to just blow away all the contents of your `~/myfolder/` dir and re-clone the project by doing the following:

```
rm -rf ~/myfolder
git clone git@github.com:myname/myproject.git ~/myfolder
```

If you have changes that you want to preserve in your project located at `~/myfolder/mysubfolder`, then we can just move stuff around to make sure that you don't lose anything. I would recommend first that you do the following to get rid of the nesting:

```
cd ~/myfolder
rm -rf .git
mv mysubfolder/* .
```

At this point, you should have all of your project's files and `.git` folder the `mysubfolder/` directory. Which you can check with `ls -al`

Next we want to check that you have a remote repository properly configured. To do so, run the command `git remote -v` hopefully you will see the following output:

```
origin  git@github.com:myname/myproject.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:myname/myproject.git (push)
```

If you don't see the output above, don't have any fear, quick fix. Just run the command:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:myname/myproject.git
```

At this point we have a reasonable directory structure and the remote repository properly configured for you. Now it's a matter of having access to that remote repository. Since the way you set it up originally was over ssh, the best option, and that's what I've shown you how to do so far, we are going to continue down that path.

First we need to check that you do have a keypair, so do the following:

```
cd ~/.ssh
ls
```

If you have a keypair then I would expect to see the two files `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`. If you don't have those files (although sometimes they are named differently), then do the following

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ls
```

Now you should have those files. `id_rsa` is your private key, which you don't want to leave your computer and should never be shared with anyone, but `id_rsa.pub` is you public key, which is a way that other people and services know how to identify you. We need to make sure that your github account has you public key `id_rsa.pub` added to it. So now do the following:

1. login to github
2. Navigate to https://github.com/settings/keys
3. Click the button "New SSH key"
4. Give it a name like "Home Desktop" or "Work laptop"
5. Copy the contents of the file `id_rsa.pub`
6. Paste the contents of that file into the key field in github
7. Click the "Add SSH Key" button

Now you should have no trouble at all push and pulling from your remote repository.

Comment: Thanks a lot rdgd, this was very helpful. Thankfully I didn't make any significant changes.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Were you able to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `https://github.com/myname/myproject`.

If this doesn't work, make sure you are signed in to the Git account you used to create the online repo. `git config --global your.name` and `git config --global your.email` should do the job.
I hope this helps!

EDIT: Are you using a branch of Debian? E.G. Raspbian, Ubuntu, etc.
If so, you should be able to run `sudo apt-get install git-gui`. After that, in your desktop, you should have a new app that says something like "Git". Open that and you should have a graphical interface, if you prefer that ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. At least they asked me for my username and password this time,

Comment: No problem! I'm glad I could help! :)

Comment: I didnt down vote it. It actually helped me. I eventually got it to work. I encountered further trouble down the line, but then added a remote origin. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points to vote.

Comment: Um... Okay... I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: @Marlo you can mark the answer with a tick.This doesnot require any points i guess..

Comment: Sure I can. No points required for that, as it turned out. However I'd also like to thank ALinuxLover for the help.